# Access value of dictionary output

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm simply trying to access the output from a variable named `parser` which is outputting a dictionary of information in it like:

```
{u'param': [u'6'], u'booID': [u'911'], u'animal': [u'cat']}
```

How can I access each parameter, and loop through each outputting the key value?

```
I tried, a number of different things including:
for parsed_val in parser:
    print parsed_val + parsed_val.keys()
```

but this throws a AttributeError of AttributeError: `'unicode' object has no attribute 'keys'`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for key, value in parser.iteritems():
    print key, value
```

Comment: I guess iteritems() is new to me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through a dictionary iterates through its *keys*.

You'll want to iterate over `dict.items()`, which iterates over a list of `(key,pair)` tuples.

You can also use `dict.iteritems` (on python 2.x), which avoids creating a list and iterates directly over the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method:

```
for key in parser.keys():
    print(str(key) + ': '+str(parser[key]))
```

`dict.keys()` is a list of all keys.

`dict.items()` is a list of of key/value pairs.

`dict.iteritems` is an iterable object of `dict.items()`.